# Trying to understand AngularJs animation transitions with keyframes

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm new in Angular and I don't have many experience with css3 (i'm a backend dev!)

I'm trying to understand how angular manage custom transitions with css3 keyframes.

I got this:

In my markup:

```
<div id="welcome-container" ng-hide="test">
...
</div>
```

in my controller:

```
$scope.test = false;
// ... doing some things that takes more than 3-4 seconds
$scope.test = true;
```

and in my CSS:

```
#welcome-container.ng-hide {
    animation:1s mycustomkeyframe;
    -webkit-animation:1s mycustomkeyframe;
}

@keyframes mycustomkeyframe {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to { opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes mycustomkeyframe {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to { opacity: 0; }
}
```

I got this example running with ng-hide-add and ng-hide-active classes but I'm really lost with keyframes. My code hide the div but it doesn't do any animation!! I want to use keyframes to do jquery-like elastic easing transitions (without jquery :P)

Anybody can help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Never used angular before, but from the CSS standpoint you don't have a class ng-hide on your div.

```
<div id="welcome-container" class="ng-hide" ng-hide="test">
Here is a bunch of text blah
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nE37R/)

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS and CSS3 are 2 totally different things

Angular can be used to attach a CSS class to the container

and after that .. based on that new CSS class . you can trigger animation start from CSS

```
$scope.my_css_clas = 'demo_classs'

<div ng-class="{{ my_css_clas }}">
```

classes in Angular are attached with `ng-class`

Answer (score -1):

I think it's not possible to animate with keyframes the ng-hide directive in the current version.

You must use another class to animate and then when animation is over do the hide action or use another ng-directive like ng-leave.